# windows phone 8 and ATL

Tags: c++, com, atl, windows-phone-8

I'm kinda new to WP8 development and I have to reuse huge legacy codebase (C++, ATL, WIN32).
Is there ATL support for Windows Phone 8? Or what?

Comment: WP8 is programmed mainly in C# so no, there isn't - ATL is for C++.

Comment: I don't think you're going to have much luck here. Time to start porting and refactoring your legacy code, I suspect.

Comment: No: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ and some of Win32 is supported on Windows Phone 8. Some COM functions are supported (as WinRT is using COM under the hood), but there's no ATL support that I'm aware of. There are also some WinRT functions available in C++ you can use.

You'll probably have to use a C# XAML UI layer (or C++ DirectX if you want), with a WinRT bridge layer to your C++ code, which will need to be compiled against the Windows Phone 8 headers and libraries.

See [MSDN Windows Phone 8 API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more details.